# Opencart: Netbeans cannot recognize parent class

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Netbeans to build my website based on Opencart 1.5.5.1. However when I open `/admin/controller/user.php` and press `CTL + click` on `Controller` class which `User` class extends from then Netbeans doesn't show me anything.

Also, because There is no code comment I tried to create my own comment but then soon realized that auto generate document template is completely broken, things like bellow if I'm using other open source:

```
/**
     * @author John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
     * @param type $name
     * @return boolean
     */
```

So, is there anyway to improve code hinting when I press CTL + click on a class name or auto generate template for comment?

Comment: Is this a custom controller file you've created as `/admin/controller/user.php` doesn't exist and isn't actually in the correct file structure to be recognised by opencart

Comment: I tried to add some code for autocomplete here https://github.com/opencart/opencart/pull/422